# How to display position: absolute div once it has display: none attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, absolute-value

i have a following div

```
   <div id="mydiv" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; 
                  left: 5px; right: 25px; bottom: 10px;"> 
   </div>
```

Then i hide it via JS with display none. Is it possible to display it back again? None of the display attributes work. Thank you

Comment: can you please show code?

Comment: You should be able to do it with `display:block`

Answer (score 2):

It can be very easily done using `jQuery`,

```
 1. $('#my_div').show()   // display the hidden div i.e sets display:block
 2. $('#my_div').toggle() // toggles the display property.
```

And using pure `javascript` it can done using,

```
var element = document.getElementById('myDiv'); 

element.style.display = 'block'; // sets display:block
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the `display` property is 'block', so just set it back to that:

```
var d = document.getElementById('my_div');

d.style.display = 'block';
```

**Edit**:

My fellow answerer has given a link to W3Schools, so I thought I'd do one better and send you to [WebPlatform.org](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/display), which is a community-driven documentation for the web.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('example-element');

el.style.display = 'none';

el.style.display = 'block';
```

For more options, [check it out](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$("#mydiv").css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$('#my_div').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

to hide and show , you can probably use visibility: `visible/hidden`, which basically divs will be there but will be hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

If you display and hide this div on some action (e.g. on `mouseover`, `onclick`  etc.) you can simply use `toggleClass` with `jquery`

css:

`.display{display:block}`

js:

`$("#mydiv").toggleClass('display')`